# Trying to Update PHP Query After Posting Data Using Axios in Vue App

Tags: javascript, php, post, vue.js, axios

I am getting a JSON object by PHP query from a service called BullHorn like so:

```
<?php echo getBhQuery('search','JobOrder','isOpen:true','id,title,categories,dateAdded,externalCategoryID,employmentType,customText12', null, 10, '-dateAdded');?>
```

However there needs to be filtering functionality on the JSON object based on user input. So I created inputs in my Vue app that grabs the user input value and I am trying to POST that value to PHP. My Axios code looks like:

```
         onSubmit () {

       axios.post('/wp-content/themes/bones/library/jobsResponse.php',{region: this.selectedLocation}, {headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest', 'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}})
       .then(function(response){
         console.log(response)
       })
       .catch(function(error){console.log(error)})
}
```

So what this is doing is when the form button is clicked the onSubmit() function runs. This then uses Axios to post data to the jobsResponse.php file. Currently the data it is posting is

```
this.selectedLocation
```

Which all that is, is  a data variable in my Vue app that is connected to dropdown input the user can use.

So then on my jobsResponse.php file I have:

```
$request_body = file_get_contents("php://input");
$data = json_decode($request_body, true);
$region = $data['region'];
```

So it is taking the posted data and assigning it to the $region variable. My biggest issue is updating the PHP query to add filtering. To filter the query by Region I would edit the query to something like so:

```
<?php echo getBhQuery('search','JobOrder','isOpen:true AND region:"Chicago Region"','id,title,categories,dateAdded,externalCategoryID,employmentType,customText12'); ?>
```

All that was added was the 'AND region:"Chicago Region"' and it would only grab jobs with the region set to Chicago Region. So in my Vue app I have a dropdown input populated with all the Regions the user can filter by. Once one is selected I want to take that data and POST it using Axios and update the PHP query to add the filter to it.

I've been running in circles trying to get this to work and have hit a wall on what I am missing. I believe I am trying to just do an Ajax like function, but using Axios post instead.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're just not concatenating that variable into your string. All you should need to do is just use that variable in your string that you pass to your function like this:

```
<?php 
echo getBhQuery('search','JobOrder','isOpen:true AND region:"'. $region .'"','id,title,categories,dateAdded,externalCategoryID,employmentType,customText12'); ?>
```